# NullPointerException Crash

Tags: java, android, http, crash

I'm getting a crash with a nullpointer expection. I'm getting the suer to sign up and I'm not sure if it's my backend that's failing. I've pointed my app to my php file and I've checked my Apache log and it is getting there.

code:

```
signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {                       
        if (usernameText.length() > 0 &&        
                        passwordText.length() > 0 && 
                        passwordAgainText.length() > 0 &&
                        eMailText.length() > 0
                        )
                    {
                        //TODO check email adress is valid

                        if (passwordText.getText().toString().equals(passwordAgainText.getText().toString())){

                            if (usernameText.length() >= 5 && passwordText.length() >= 5) {

                                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                                        String result = new String();
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            result = imService.signUpUser(usernameText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    passwordText.getText().toString(), 
                                                    eMailText.getText().toString());

                                            handler.post(new Runnable(){

                                                public void run() {
                                                    if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_RES_SIGN_UP_SUCCESFULL)) {
                                                        showDialog(SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED)){
                                                        showDialog(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED);
                                                    }
                                                    else  if (result.equals(SERVER_RES_SIGN_UP_FAILED)) 
                                                    {
                                                        showDialog(SIGN_UP_FAILED);
                                                    }           
                                                }

                                            });
                                        }

                                    };
                                    thread.start();
                            }
                            else{
                                showDialog(USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }                           
                        }
                        else {
                            showDialog(TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS);
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        showDialog(FILL_ALL_FIELDS);

                    }               
                }           
            });

            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                {                   
                }               
            }});


        }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {       

        switch (id) 
        {
            case TYPE_SAME_PASSWORD_IN_PASSWORD_FIELDS:         
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_type_same_password_in_password_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();          
            case FILL_ALL_FIELDS:               
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_fill_all_fields)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_FAILED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_failed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_USERNAME_CRASHED:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_username_crashed)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            case SIGN_UP_SUCCESSFULL:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.signup_successfull)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })        
                .create();  
            case USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_LENGTH_SHORT:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this)       
                .setMessage(R.string.username_and_password_length_short)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                    }
                })        
                .create();
            default:
                return null;

        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        bindService(new Intent(SignUp.this, IMService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
    }



}
```

LogCat:
     05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522): java.lang.NullPointerException 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.mekya.SignUp$2$1$1.run(SignUp.java:113) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 

05-21 13:47:22.237: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you format your code?  It's a bit hard to read that and the error message.

Comment: I'll try, I don't know why it did that.

Comment: Looks like `result` is `null`...

Comment: try Log.e("TAG",result+""); then you will know what is coming as result

Comment: Thanks @K-ballo that fixed it! Now, I just need to check my backend as result is null for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `result` is `null` ....

Comment: Could you suggest how to solve this issue? I have the same problem